# how to file.write() an empty string if dictionary produces a KeyError in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.4

I have a particular problem with json files. The following code reads json, and writes to a txt file. I have shortened the code for readability, in my real code it is hundereds of fields and write statements.

```
import os
import json


def _getjson(filename):
    """ returns a list of dictionaries """
    if not os.path.exists(filename): return []
    with open(filename, 'r') as openfileobject:
        data = json.loads(openfileobject.read())
    return data

def writefile(filename, data):
    """writes to file"""
    with open(filename, 'w') as f:
        for d in data:
            f.write(d['field1'] + ' ' + d['field2'] + ' ' + d['field3'] + '\n')
            ## a lot more code here


def main():
    filename = r'c:\input.json'
    data = _getjson(filename)
    outfile = r'c:\output.txt'
    writefile(outfile, data)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The problem is, sometimes a field is not in json, and it produces a `KeyError`
While I can trap this with a `try: except KeyError`. It would mean that I need to put this try around every field in my `writefile` function.

Is there a way that without changing the `f.write()` statements, that upon `KeyError` it will write an empty string ? (so I do not have to capture this in hundereds of `try` blocks)

So this is a dictionary problem, I have no problem with the json itself. I cannot control which fields are in my input, so one file may have `field1` and `field2`. The next could have all three, or only one. The json part works, just that I will be missing some fields, sometimes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`dict.get`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get):

```
f.write(d.get('field1', '') + ' ' +
        d.get('field2', '') + ' ' +
        d.get('field3', '') + '\n')
```

`get()` returns the value for *key*, or given *default* or `None`.

Comment: You could also apply the `join()` idea to this as well: `f.write(' '.join(d.get(k, '') for k in ['field1', 'field2', 'field3']) + '\n')`

Answer (score 2):

More simpler is `str.join` with `dict.values`.

`f.write(' '.join(d.values()))`

or if values are not strings use genexps like

`f.write(' '.join(str(value) for value in d.values()))`

Comment: `d.values()` has arbitrary order, or in other words no order at all. That might not matter, but most of the time it does.

Comment: `dict.values()` will not work for me, as I cannot select the exact key I want to write to the file (and format and put other text around)... but thank you for your answer, I learned another trick, which I will use in the future !